# Can't figure out why the "str x6, [x7]" instruction does not work in arm64 assembly

Tags: assembly, arm64

I'm trying to set a variable to 0x70 and examine the value using jtag debugger.(arm64)
So I set x6 to 0x70 and store the value to the address of `myval2`.

```
.global myval
.global myval2

...(skip)
reset:
    /* Allow the board to save important registers */
    mov x6, #0x70
    ldr x7, =myval2
    str x6, [x7]
    b   save_boot_params
...(skip)

.data
myval: .long 0x11111111
myval2: .long 0x22222222
```

But after supposedly the program has passed above point, when I examine the value of myval and myval2, they are still 0x11111111 and 0x22222222.

But when I did (not sure, similar to this)

```
ldr x6, =myval
ldr x7, =myval2
str x6, [x7]
...(skip)
.data
myval: .long 0x11111111
myval2: .long 0x0x40025bc
```

I could see after the point, the two values were both 0x11111111 as I expected (but I can't reproduce it now..).
Why does the first code(`mov x6, #0x70`) not work?  and why does the second code(`ldr x6, =myval`) not work?  Sorry for this stupid looking question. I understand immediate value less than 12 bits can be expressed in one instruction.
**==> ADD :**
I found through qemu test, it is the `str x6, [x7]` instruction that isn't working. Even though it is executed, when I examine the address in `x7`, the value hasn't changed. In what case can this happen? I can see the core is in EL3.
**==> UPDATE :**
I tried writing to differnet location (last time was to iram area, this time to sdram area(temporarily using iram)) and it worked. so it is not the code problem but a system problem.

Comment: Your first code should work.  Make sure you actually compile and ran that code.  Some times people forget one of the steps and accidentally run outdated code.

Comment: Do you have the equivalent of make clean?  Delete objects and binaries and build fresh, maybe it is not re-assembling your code for some reason based on your make/build system.

Comment: create and check the disassembly (IMO should always generate a disassembly) to see that the binary does contain that code.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Since I'm home now I'll check tomorrow if I'm doing the changed executable (including disassembling it).

Comment: I'm sure I'm doing the experiment with correct compiled code. (actually the code is loaded into 0x4000000 from SD card and jumped into). I tried running the program on qemu machine (modified arm 'virt' machine which is very close to our board including the SRAM and SDRM memory map), but the `str x6, [x7]` command doesn't write the value in `x6` into the address in `x7`. I mean when x6 contains 0x40025b8 and x6 contains 0x40025bc, the `str x6, [x7]` doesn't change the memory content at 0x40025bc.

Comment: Might be related to cache issue? Otherwise, that should work. Have you also tried to change that variable from another subroutine and check right after the routine?

Comment: @asevindik the caches are disabled and because I read memory using ocd (on chip debugger) there is no cache effect. Later I tried writing to 0x807e0000 and it is wrtten ok. Maybe I'll ask my colleague to do simulation with this binary.

Comment: @ChanKim I don't think that ocd has capability to prevent the cache coherency etc. or cache effects. But ok, you said caches are disabled.